# Using a url scheme on NSURL() results to nil

Tags: xcode, whatsapp, viber, deeplink

**Language Used**: Swift 2.3

Viber's url scheme for sending a message is `viber://forward?text=`

Whatsapp's url scheme for sending a message is `whatsapp://send?text=`

The problem is NSURL seems to think that url's that don't have `.` on them are not urls because this code seems to result to nil

```
let someString = "This is some kind of long string"
print(NSURL(string: "viber://forward?text=\(someString)"))

print(NSURL(string: "viber://whatsapp://send=\(someString)"))
```

This results to a log which looks like this.

```
nil
nil
```

Which means I can't use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openUrl(someUrl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some characters that can't be placed inside a `URL`/`NSURL`.

You'd have to parse `someString` to replace these characters using this **String extension**

`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())`

For example:

```
var someString = "This is some kind of long string"

someString = someString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```